# What does grep do when using a dollar sign in the search term?

Tags: grep

I wanted to find `$featuredicon` variable in my php files, and I ran `grep -ir "$featuredicon"`

I understood that dollar sign is reserved character in shell. But what does it actually do? Did I modify my php files? I'm afraid I did something bad...

next time I will run `grep -ir "\$featuredicon"`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Remember to accept the answer that _actually answers your question_, which is not necessarily the first answer you receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why every single line of every single file was listed was due to variable substitution of your shell.

When you call

```
grep -ir "$featuredicon" *
```

`bash` will evaluate that. It will look up the variable `$featuredicon` and put it into your command. Guess what `$featuredicon` most likely is?

Right, nothing. So what you're actually doing is:

```
grep -ir "" *
```

And that matches every line of every file.

#### Old Answer

The dollar sign (`$`) is a placeholder for `end-of-line` in regular expression (I assume the same is true for grep).

If you want to search for a dollar sign, use `'\$'`.

Be sure to check the StackOverflow question: [How to grep for the dollar symbol ($)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759926/how-to-grep-for-the-dollar-symbol)

Comment: Ty, escaping part I figured it out myself.

Comment: I was just curious what it did to my php files, or why it was outputing everything to terminal.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: I updated my answer to address your specific concerns. I was misinterpreting your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` cannot modify files on its own; it has caused no damage.

Comment: But what does it do? why did it print all lines from every single file? And how to use $ in grep for what purpose? ty for putting my ocd mind to ease :)

Comment: This is not an answer and I feel stupid telling you this :P

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: @Oliver: "Did I modify my php files?"

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I guess, you're right. Sorry for judging too quickly.